# Wordpress - List all posts (with proper_pagination)

Tags: wordpress

On the Wordpress site I'm working on, it lists posts by category, but I am also after a page that lists ALL the posts (with pagination, showing 10 per page). How would I go about achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could create a new page template with this loop in it:

```
<?php 
$paged = get_query_var('paged')? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'paged' => $paged,
];
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- then the pagination links -->
<?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts', $wp_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 19):

For others who might be Googling this...  If you have replaced the front page of your site with a *static* page, but still want your list of posts to appear under a separate link, you need to:

1. Create an empty page (and specify any URL/slug you like)
2. Under **Settings > Reading**, choose this new page as your "Posts page"

Now when you click the link to this page in your menu, it should list all your recent posts  (no messing with code required).

Comment: thanks for your answer! 

quick question: how do you edit the template of the page after doing this?

Answer (score 2):

A bit more fancy solution based on @Gavins answer

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: List-all-chronological
*/

function trimStringIfTooLong($s) {
    $maxLength = 60;
    
    if (strlen($s) > $maxLength) {
        echo substr($s, 0, $maxLength - 5) . ' ...';
    } else {
        echo $s;
    }
}

?>

<ul>
<?php
$query = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => 'ASC' );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($query);

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Link to <?php the_title_attribute() ?>">
        <?php the_time( 'Y-m-d' ) ?> 
        <?php trimStringIfTooLong(get_the_title()); ?>
    </a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts published so far.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: How to add pagination for more than 10 posts?