# Wordpress - category.php - not all posts, or incorrect categories are appearing in category archive. (pagination confusion etc)

Tags: wordpress, templates, categories

For the life of me I cannot understand why I am having so much trouble getting my category archives to work.

All I want is for the category based on the permalink:

http://siteurl/parent_cat/child_cat

to show all the posts in that category, with 10 per page, and paginate properly.

Without anything modifying the query, the site only shows about 8 of posts on page-1, then 2 posts on page-2, and none on page-3, yet there are over 44 posts in this category.

If I use [the solution on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794622/wordpress-list-all-posts-with-proper-pagination), or modify the query in any way, it seems to show posts from every single category.

My template, category.php, is essentially a copy of the index.php, so why is it having so many issues limiting the posts by category??

For reference, the category structure is so:

Posts (parent)
- Music (child)
- Art (child)
- Film (child)
- Misc (child)

Then the url is as such:
http://siteurl/posts/music
etc

Is it simply querying all the posts from the parent category? If so, how does one force it only to get posts from the specific and current child category determined by the permalink?

Comment: you should'nt have to do any querying on the cateogry page. Copy the code fro category.php of 2010 and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

If your category.php is using the `have_post(); the_post();` aka "The Loop", you can't have the correct pagination if you force to display specific number of post in a page.

"The Loop" is always following the number of post per page set in your admin panel. 
If you change that (number of post per page) in your admin panel to 10, you will get the correct pagination. But if you want that setting unchanged, you need to query the post for yourself and display it without using the "The Loop".

You can use the `foreach($post in $posts)` instead of `have_post();the_post();`.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can try work with twentyten template and try to specify the category

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=special_cat&showposts=10'); ?>
```