# Wordpress Display All Posts

Tags: wordpress, blogs, posts

THis may be really easy but i have searched and search and cant find anything.  What is the default blog page?

I am trying to find the page that will display excerpts of all my blog posts regardless of category or tags.  I know that I can do www.xyz.com/category/widgets to get a list of all the posts in that category.  What I am trying to do is just list all my blog posts without any filter.

Is there a default page in wordpress to achieve this?  Thank you.

Comment: A similar question was posed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794622/wordpress-list-all-posts-with-proper-pagination

Answer (score 8):

If you want it for all categories/tags/fron_page, there is very quick sollution - go to /wp-admin/options-reading.php and set the number of posts to -1 - it is not normally possible as the input got min=1, but you can change it easily with e.g. browser developer console.

If you want just one page with all posts, you can simply create template or shortcode, with http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts and numberposts set to -1 and show what you need, e.g.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1); 
$posts= get_posts( $args );
if ($posts) {
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

For others who might be Googling this...  If you have replaced the front page of your site with a *static* page, but still want your list of posts to appear under a separate link, you need to:

1. Create an empty page (and specify any URL/slug you like)
2. Under **Settings > Reading**, choose this new page as your "Posts page"

Now when you click the link to this page in your menu, it should list all your recent posts  (no messing with code required).

*(Disclaimer: I posted this same answer to [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22370643/195835).)*

Answer (score 5):

This all depends on your theme, you'd need a blog.php, page-blog.php, archive.php (you get the idea).

It will be a php page that's got a basic `WP_Query()` with no definition of category or anything.

You'd be able to define this either in:

1. Settings > Reading --- Blog Page
2. Theme Options --- (something like) Blog Categories [pick all]
3. define it for all posts in the PHP file itself

hopefully this helps, sorry there's not a "do that 'here'" answer for you :/

Comment: To build on this answer, if nothing can be found in any custom settings, then Wordpress' Codex on their [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) will be extremely useful in helping pinpoint exactly which file should be created or edited.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for this - I also found another way ...

In your theme's files - look for blog-page.php

If it is not there - copy blog.php as blog-page.php

In blog-page.php - change description to be Blog (Page). this causes the template to be listed as Blog (Page) where you can use the template your wordpress page uses.

Customize your sidebar with categories and recent posts widgets....